# Postfix: SMTP, use port 587 rather than 465

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, smtp, postfix, sasl

I have set up a mail server on AWS EC2 using the instructions from Flurdy: http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/ it has mostly gone well.

My issue is that I would prefer to use SMTP port 587 with TLS rather than 465 with SSL. I believe this is a relevant requirement as port 465 is considered not future proof.

The instructions on the Flurdy site are designed to allow both, however I can not get 587 to work! 465 with SSL works a charm.

I should also mention that this build uses sasl with MySQL and I think this is why I have not found much help when I Google the errors. I believe the error lies somewhere in the SASL / PAM arena, but I have had no luck.

Here are some of the log outputs:

MAIL.LOG

```
postfix/smtpd[11328]: connect from MY.ISP.PROVIDER[MY.IP.0.0]
postfix/smtpd[11328]: Anonymous TLS connection established from MY.ISP.PROVIDER[MY.IP.0.0]: TLSv1.2 with cipher AES128-SHA256 (128/128 bits)
postfix/smtpd[11328]: warning: SASL authentication failure: client response doesn't match what we generated (tried bogus)
postfix/smtpd[11328]: warning: MY.ISP.PROVIDER[MY.IP.0.0]: SASL DIGEST-MD5 authentication failed: authentication failure
postfix/smtpd[11328]: warning: SASL authentication failure: cannot connect to saslauthd server: No such file or directory
postfix/smtpd[11328]: warning: MY.ISP.PROVIDER[MY.IP.0.0]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: generic failure
postfix/smtpd[11328]: lost connection after AUTH from MY.ISP.PROVIDER[MY.IP.0.0]
postfix/smtpd[11328]: disconnect from MY.ISP.PROVIDER[MY.IP.0.0]*
```

My master.cf

```
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,reject
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous,noplaintext
  -o smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous

smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous,noplaintext
  -o smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous
```

There is also other conf such as AMAVIS, but I suspect this is all ok.

The SQL log shows all the connections and queries working correctly.

I have used TELNET for testing and it simply closes the connection when I attempt the auth with port 587. If I open port 25 on my server then I can do complete a successful AUTH LOGIN.

Here is the difference in EHLO response with 25 (when open) and 587. I noticed 587 does not include AUTH. Is this the problem??

```
$ telnet my.mailserver.com 587
Trying MY.IP.0.0...
Connected to my.mailserver.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 MY-EC2-SERVER-NAME.localdomain ESMTP Postfix
EHLO my.mailserver.com
250-MY-EC2-SERVER-NAME.localdomain
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN

$ telnet my.mailserver.com 25
Trying MY.IP.0.0...
Connected to my.mailserver.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 MY-EC2-SERVER-NAME.localdomain ESMTP Postfix
EHLO my.mailserver.com
250-MY-EC2-SERVER-NAME.localdomain
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN CRAM-MD5 DIGEST-MD5
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

I have restarted the services postfix and saslauthd a number of times. 
I have also double checked the passwords and usernames in the DB.
I have been over the instructions and checked for misconfiguration and spelling mistakes, although this is likely what it will be in the end :-)

The server is UBUNTU 13.10

Please let me know if I can supply any further info to help debugging.

All thoughts welcome!

Comment: This kind of question would get better exposure on ServerVault. But while we are at it I think AUTH is available after TLS has established. Might want to Google how STARTTLS works..

Answer (score 1):

I also followed [Flurdy's tutorial](http://flurdy.com/docs/postfix/) and had a similar problem: I could only send mail through port 25 (smtpd), but not through 587 (submission). I found out the problem to be exactly that, according to his instructions, port 25 was configured to run in chroot but 587 was not - it seems to be an error in the tutorial. Check out this part of flurdy's instructions:

> By default only the normal smtp service is enabled, which is fine. But
>   I prefer to enable submission (port 587), so that clients can use it,
>   and I can restrict them to TLS only. Also enabled smtps service (port
>   465), for some compatebility with some older clients (outlook express
>   etc).

Right below this text you can find this line, stating the daemon for the submission port will not use chroot:

```
submission inet n - n - - smtpd
```

I know this because my original `/etc/postfix/master.cf` file had comments showing this legend:

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
```

Right below the option list for the submission port lies the following line, which configures smtps (port 465):

```
smtps inet n - - - - smtpd
```

From this you can see it is using the default (I guess the `-` sign means it will use the default, which is to use chroot).

Ok, then, when you look at the SASL authentication section, where it says:

> Change how SASLAUTHD is run:

you can see the `OPTIONS` variable contains the following path:

```
# Switch this to be under postfix's spool
# And add -r so that the realm(domain) is part of the username
OPTIONS="-r -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
```

Again, with help from my originally commented `/etc/default/saslauthd` file, I noted this clear explanation:

```
# Other options (default: -c -m /var/run/saslauthd)
# Note: You MUST specify the -m option or saslauthd won't run!
#
# WARNING: DO NOT SPECIFY THE -d OPTION.
# The -d option will cause saslauthd to run in the foreground instead of as
# a daemon. This will PREVENT YOUR SYSTEM FROM BOOTING PROPERLY. If you wish
# to run saslauthd in debug mode, please run it by hand to be safe.
#
# See /usr/share/doc/sasl2-bin/README.Debian for Debian-specific information.
# See the saslauthd man page and the output of 'saslauthd -h' for general
# information about these options.
#
# Example for chroot Postfix users: "-c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
# Example for non-chroot Postfix users: "-c -m /var/run/saslauthd"
#
# To know if your Postfix is running chroot, check /etc/postfix/master.cf.
# If it has the line "smtp inet n - y - - smtpd" or "smtp inet n - - - - smtpd"
# then your Postfix is running in a chroot.
# If it has the line "smtp inet n - n - - smtpd" then your Postfix is NOT
# running in a chroot.
OPTIONS="-r -c -m /var/spool/postfix/var/run/saslauthd"
```

Since my `OPTIONS` variable was clearly specifying the chroot case, I just changed my submission configuration at `/etc/postfix/master.cf` to also use chroot. After restarting the server - just to make sure all the services were properly restarted - it worked out like a charm, now I can send email either through port 25 or 587.

Hope it also helps you out! I also lost quite some time to see this...